# Having trouble connecting via 3G network using my iPhone 4

Tags: iphone

I'm having trouble using the 3g network I do believe it was a day or so after apple software update 7.1.2 IOS. I can use wifi but not 3G network for some reason.  So I did all of the stuff people were saying reset the  phone. So did and then I even did the airplane mode on and off, then shut off the phone. Nothing seems to work. When I'm at work I have no Wifi and resetting the phone over and over has me extremely frustrated.

I have searched for a solution and everything I have been finding about this problem was last year in 2013. Are there different troubleshooting steps or ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if your network carrier data options are enabled (probably through your account with the carrier).

If so check to see if you have your data turned on Settings > Cellular > Cellular Data switch is to green.

Reset network settings Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings

If none of the above work you can always take your backplate off and ensure that your antenna is still connected to your logic board (plenty of tutorials online)